# Trying to copy a row in excel and paste into another excel sheet, but I'm getting #### and 0 as the first and last value

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

using openpyxl I'm trying to copy a row from one excel file and paste it as a column in a secondary excel file, but I keep getting ####### and 0 in place of the first and last cells of the column when pasted.

```
import openpyxl as xl


# opening the source excel file
filename = "test.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

# opening the secondary source file
filname2 = "historicalweeklydata.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filname2)
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0]

# opening the destination excel file
filename3 = "test3.xlsx"
wb3 = xl.load_workbook(filename3)
ws3 = wb3.active


# save file with new name
filename4 = "new.xlsx"


# calculate total number of rows and
# columns in source excel file
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column

mr2 = ws2.max_row
mc2 = ws2.max_column
ws3.insert_cols(2)
ws3.insert_cols(3)

# copying the cell values from source
# excel file to destination excel file
for i in range(1, mr + 1):
    for j in range(1, mc + 1):
        # reading cell value from source excel file
        readSource = ws1.cell(row=i, column=1)

        # writing the read value to destination excel file
        ws3.cell(row=i, column=2).value = readSource.value

for i in range(1, mr2 + 1):
    for j in range(1, mc2 + 1):
        # reading cell value from secondary excel file
        readSource2 = ws2.cell(row=8, column=i)

        # writing the read value to destinaction excel file
        ws3.cell(row=i, column=3).value = readSource2.value
# saving the destination excel file
wb3.save(filename4)
```

Comment: `######` just means the data is too wide for the column width.  Make the column wider.

Comment: The `#####` usually means in Excel that the cell is too narrow to display its content. Enlarge the width of the column the cell is in.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the ###### issue, currently trying to figure out though why I get a 0 at the end of the cell though, the file its copying from has a number in it.

Comment: The loops don't make a great deal of sense to me. I'd suggest you use `zip()`